# Saving EditText to External Storage and Intent in single button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to try to save multiple EditText input to a txt file. I also want the button to intent to another activity. I've try to implement the code but my apps crash when i click the button. 
This is my code.

MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name, numbTent, pangkat, date, time, penyelia, pegawai;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    numbTent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numbTent);
    pangkat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pangkat);
    date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    penyelia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.penyelia);
    pegawai = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pegawai);
}

public void SaveInfo(View v) {

    String state;
    state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Semak Operasi Mampatan SRC");
        if(Dir.exists())
        {
            Dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(Dir,"AttendantInfo.txt");
        String Info1 = name.getText().toString();
        String Info2 = numbTent.getText().toString();
        String Info3 = pangkat.getText().toString();
        String Info4 = date.getText().toString();
        String Info5 = time.getText().toString();
        String Info6 = penyelia.getText().toString();
        String Info7 = pegawai.getText().toString();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(Info1.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info2.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info3.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info4.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info5.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info6.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(Info7.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
            name.setText("");
            numbTent.setText("");
            pangkat.setText("");
            date.setText("");
            time.setText("");
            penyelia.setText("");
            pegawai.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Info Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Storage not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChecklistType.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.hp.semakoperasimampatansrc.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:hint="@string/nama"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/pangkat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numbTent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/pangkat" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:id="@+id/penyelia"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/penyelia" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:id="@+id/pegawai"
    android:layout_below="@+id/penyelia"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/pegawai" />



<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/numbTent"
    android:hint="@string/NumTent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="@string/time"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="datetime"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:hint="@string/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pangkat"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_submit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="SaveInfo"/>
```

Comment: Post your crash log then

Comment: Where can i find the crash log?

Comment: @Eizzuddin see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Comment: i get this log > W/System.err: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied) : /storage/emulated/0/Semak Operasi Mampatan SRC. 
Ive already add this line on the manifest but still crash. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this block is wrong :

```
    if(Dir.exists())
    {
        Dir.mkdir();
    }
```

What you want is if the directory doesn't exist,make it.So when you new `.txt` file ,it crashes.

```
    if(!Dir.exists())
    {
        Dir.mkdir();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 6.0 and above, the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE needs to be requested to the user. So you need to check if your application has the permission at startup to avoid your app crash. Something like:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
//File write logic here
return true;
```

}

And if not, then you can request for the permissiong using:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will show a permission request dialog to the user and the user can decide whether or not to allow your application to have the permission. 
You can perform desired actions depending upon the result of the permission request in the following function.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String [] permissions, int [] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // permission was granted. Write file logic
        } else {
            // permission denied
         }
         return;
    }
}
```

}